# c# streamwriter append text under each other

Tags: c#

I want to append lines to my file. I am using code:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("gamedata.txt", true);
sw.Write(the_final);
sw.Dispose();
```

at the moment it's outputting everything in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sw.WriteLine(the_final);`  or `sw.Write(the_final + "\n");`

But much cleaner:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText("gamedata.txt", the_final + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use writeline for writing in a new line `sw.WriteLine(the_final)`

It Writes a line terminator to the text stream

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebb1kw70.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WriteLine()` method instead of `Write()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is when you're constructing your output into the variable: the_final

You need to insert new lines. You can do this by something along these lines:

```
the_final = "My First Line" + "\r\n";
the_final += "My Second Line!" + "\r\n";
thirdline = "My Third Line!";
the_final += thirdline + "\r\n";
```

The "\r\n" will produce the carriage return you're looking for.

The other suggestions everyone is making will only append 1 new line to the end of your output, leaving the rest on a single line still.

Comment: Shouldn't there also be a `+ "\r\n"; after `"My First Line"`?

Comment: Yup, it's just an example really of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`sw.Writeline();` writes a new line at the end.
`sw.Write();` does not append a new line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sw.WriteLine()` over `Write()`

MSDN:
Writes a line terminator to the text stream.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline character manually

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("gamedata.txt", true);
sw.Write(the_final + "\n");
sw.Dispose();
```

or use the [writeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline.aspx) method

This question is easily answered by a short google search.It's good form to do a bit of research prior to posting

Answer (score 0):

While everyone else has pretty much answered your initial question, may I also suggest this improvement?

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("gamedata.txt", true))
{
    sw.WriteLine(the_final);
}
```

When you have an object that inherits from `IDisposable`, it's good form to use `using` instead of disposing it manually. For one thing, `using` will dispose your object even if an exception is encountered.

[Using documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, how do you close a topic as answered on stackoverflow?